# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'zygpar' not found

Tags: r

Error in eval (expr, envir, enclos): object zygpar not found.

```
nl <- read.table ("hybrid2.csv", header=T, na=".")
    describe(nl, skew=F)

    # Recode Data for Analysis - Rescale variables to have variances     around    1.0
nl$orf1  <- nl$orfsummer0ppvt00
nl$orf2  <- nl$orfsummer1ppvt11
nl$nwf1   <- nl$nwfsummer1ppvt11
nl$nwf2   <- nl$nwfsummer1ppvt11
nl$fcat1    <- nl$fcat0ppvt00
nl$fcat2    <- nl$fcat0ppvt00
nl$rti1  <- nl$rtisum10
nl$rti2  <- nl$rtisum11
nl$zygpar  <- nl$zyg_par


# Select Variables for Analysis
vars      <- c('orf','nwf','fcat','rti') 
nv        <- 4       # number of variables
ntv       <- nv*2    # number of total variables
selVars   <- paste(vars,c(rep(1,nv),rep(2,nv)),sep="")

# Select Random Subset to reduce time to Fit Examples
testData  <- head(nl,n=500)

# Select Data for Analysis
mzData    <- subset(testData, zygpar==1, selVars)
dzData    <- subset(testData, zygpar==2, selVars)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
The error I get is 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'zygpar' not found

Answer (score 1):

So I've gotten progressively frustrated at questions that a) present less information than would be reasonably be offered if you were presenting this question to a supervisor, and b) suggest no effort (or perhaps knowledge) of the basics of the R language. So I originally posted and then deleted a comment that said: `Have you even looked at str(testData)?????`.

Knowing what sort of "object" you are working with is fundamental to R programming (and  in point of fact to probably every programming language). (So I think:) The subset function was unable to find a column in testData named `zygpar`. Why was that? I have no way of knowing ... because I am not at your elbow and cannot ask you to immediately type `names(nl)` which would tell me the valid names in the `nl`-object. But since you made `testData` from `nl`, we would have expected the names of `testData` to be the same as those of `nl`. So `names` or `str` will tell you either list element names or data.frame column names (since data.frames are merely a special form of list.

So on one level (the SO level) what you are "doing wrong" is failing to provide enough information. On the individual, personal level what you are "doing wrong" is diving into a computer language without studying  its logical and semantic basis and learning the functions and methods that let you examine the objects that you are manipulating.

So this is arguably only an "SO comment", but I do honestly believe that the answer will be obvious to an experienced R programmer if you only offer the results of either `names(testData)` or `str(testData)`.